# Does isc-dhcp-server-ldap work with DHCPv6?

Tags: ldap, dhcpv6

I'm trying to add IPv6 to my network, which uses DHCPv4 with its data stored in an LDAP server. I'm using the Ubuntu module `isc-dhcp-server-ldap` v4.4.1 to configure the DHCPv4 server and I'm very pleased with it.

I would like to configure my DHCPv6 server the same way. I realise that DHCPv6 options differ from DHCPv4 options and that there is no direct translation from DHCPv4 to DHCPv6.

I would be grateful if someone could confirm that `isc-dhcp-server-ldap` does in fact support IPv6 and DHCPv6. I have no reason to suspect otherwise, but my attempts at searching for information (things like "LDAP DHCPv6") have revealed suspiciously little information, and a question I placed about this in the Ubuntu support forums elicited no response.

Steve

Comment: Yes, and the [README](https://fossies.org/linux/dhcp/contrib/ldap/README.ldap) even has an example.

Comment: Shame on me for not thinking to look at the README. But thank you for pointing this out. It contains all the information I need.